# Integral Domain Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am a little confused about the integral domain definition. My professor gave us two books and here are the definitions each one give:

Book 1
A commutative ring R with identity is called an integral domain if, for every $a,b\in R$ such that $ab=0$, either $a=0$ or $b=0$

Book 2
An integral domain is a commutative ring with identity element 1 in which the product of any two nonzero elements is nonzero

Now is there a difference between these two definitions?

Comment: Hint: contrapositive${}$

Comment: What wj32 wrote: in one you're given the definition $\,A\longrightarrow B\,$ ,and in the other one the definition $\,\neg B\longrightarrow \neg A\,$ . It's, logically, the same.

Comment: Note that it is often desired that integral domains be nontrivial (i.e. one does not allow for rings with $0=1$ to be integral domains), and it might be worth checking to see whether these books include that condition.

Comment: I don't know if your books allow the zero ring, i.e., the unique (up to isomorphism) ing in which $1=0$, but if they do, then both of these definitions are missing the condition that $1\neq 0$.

Comment: It must be important when two comments in succession mention it in almost the same way.

Answer (score 2):

By using the contrapositive of one statement, we recover the definition of the other.